# How to stop elements of the Visual Studio (2019) toolbar snapping to the left

Tags: visual-studio-2019, toolbar, visual-studio-2005

In Visual Studio 2005 elements of the tool bar could be moved so that they were all near the centre of the screen like this: [image of visual studio 2005 tool bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYzb3.png)

In Visual Studio 2019 I have not been able to find a way to format the tool bar in a similar way, with a space to the left of the toolbar.

I have tried looking through the customize tool bar menu and looking for resources online, and adding a new menu to the left of the toolbar and setting its name to spaces.